# Executing a shell script in the current directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to list the five folders consuming the most space. Here is what I have:

```
$ du -m --max-depth 1 | sort -rn 5
```

This works fine, but how do get this code to check the directory that it is called from?

Comment: I have a feeling that there is more to the question; executing `du` in this fashion (directly via command line, or via a shell script, or via a shell function) can _only_ execute in your current working directory. What are you seeing? What would you rather see?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this answers your question:

```
$dir=`pwd`

if [ $dir = "some_directory_you_are_expecting" ]
then
    du -m --max-depth 1 | sort -rn 5
else
    do_some_other_thing
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving "5" as the file to be sorted, but you want to sort the output from du. Perhaps your sort is different. Mine is from http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

here:

```
$ echo 'du -sm * | sort -rn | head -n5 ' > ~/bin/top5.sh 
raptor: ~
$ chmod 755 ~/bin/top5.sh
raptor: ~
$ top
top      top5.sh  
raptor: ~
$ top5.sh 
606     src
532     svn
407     tmp
349     images
45      workspace
raptor: ~
$ cd /usr/
raptor: /usr
$ top5.sh 
du: cannot read directory `lib64/mozilla/extensions': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `lost+found': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `share/ggz/modules': Permission denied
1928    lib64
1842    share
1779    src
492     bin
457     lib32
```